# How to check if an array of DOM-node text values are equal to a certain string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, protractor

The goal is to take an array of names and check if all of them are equal to `e2e`.
I have a collection of objects created via protractor's `element.all(by.css(...)`. In the next step I need to check if there is an element in the array with a text value other than what I need.

I've tried to create an array from the collection I have and check it with the `Array.some` method like this:

```
const accountNames = element.all(by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)'))
const notMatch = Array.from(accountNames).some(element => 
element.getText() !== 'e2e')

expect(notMatch).toBeFalsy()
```

I expect to get an array of strings and a boolean result for the comparison of elements to a certain text.

I receive an empty array though. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you get an empty array from the `some` function? It is not possible it can return only `boolean`. Or you get an empty array in the `accountNames` variable?

Comment: The `accountNames` gives me a collection of objects, as I see it.
The `Array.from(accountNames)` gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected, but I wonder if there's an answer that looks better:

```
it('filters kits by account hierarchy', () => {
mapPage.filter('e2e')
const accNames = element.all(by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)')).getText()
.then(text => Array.from(text).some(elem => elem !== 'e2e'))

expect(accNames).toBeFalsy()
})
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood your initial requirement. You say `The goal is to take an array of names and check if all of them are equal to e2e`. Does this mean you want a false value if the text in any of the array element is **not** `e2e`?

Comment: This logic works both ways `.some(elem => elem !== 'e2e')` is falsy and `.some(elem => elem === 'e2e')` is truthy. But as I need to check all elements to be true, it is enough to find at least one element to be false.

Answer (score 0):

There a number of methods you can call on element arrays [which you can see here](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder). I would to accomplish this using either filter or reduce.

There are two further approaches you could try but I'm not sure either are more straight forward than the solution you have come up with.

**Reduce**

```
//Using reduce we will call a function on every element in an array and 
// end up with a single value (true ro false in this case)
let allValuesAreE2E = $$('td > p:nth-child(3)').reduce(function (acc, elem) {
    //If accumlator value is false
    if (!acc) return false;

    //return whether or not 
    return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text === 'e2e';
    });
}, 'initVal');

expect(allValuesAreE2E).toBeFalsy();
```

Filter will execute a function on every element in an array and remove the ones which do not meet a certain condition (in your case text = e2e)

```
const allContainE2E = $$('td > p:nth-child(3)')).count().then(numElements => 
  return numElements === $$('td > p:nth-child(3)')).filter(element => {
        return element.getText().then(text => text === 'e2e')
      })
  })
{

expect(allContainE2E.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0) // use Jasmine
```

Comment: `console.log(containingE2e.length, typeof containingE2e)` shows `undefined` and `object`

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, please try again.

Comment: I saw it and ran it without your typo

Comment: Are you certain your initial object is being found correctly? Does this command produce a number `element.all(by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)')).count().then(num => {console.log(num)})`

Comment: @ІгорДроненко Try this next `element.all(by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)')).getText().then(text=> {console.log(text)})`. This should print out the text within all the cells and allow you to see which one are being found. Note: actually has a mistake in my answer which Yong identified (using .length instead of .count() can you try my answer once again?)

Comment: Well, that shows `[ 'e2e', 'e2e' ]`. Now have to extract that to array

Comment: Which command produced that? The one in the answer or the last one I posted in the comment?

Comment: The one from comment.

Comment: Weird, this indicates that there are two elements on youe page that match this locator `by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)')` and both have 'e2e' as their text. I'm really not sure why the initial command i posted in the comments returned `14`. Any chance you could post some of the HTML for the table?

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. But this code works as expected:
  `it('filters kits by account hierarchy', () => {
    mapPage.filter('e2e')
    const accNames = element.all(by.css('td > p:nth-child(3)')).getText()
      .then(text => Array.from(text).some(elem => elem !== 'e2e'))

    expect(accNames).toBeFalsy()
  })`

Comment: please edit your answer to be the same as your 3rd comment to it and i'll accept it, coz it really helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear it @ІгорДроненко however there is no need to accept the answer if you managed to get it working yourself, it is possible to accept your own answer which may be the correct thing to do in this case. I did add some other potential solutions you can try but honestly I'm not sure either or them are nicer than the one you have come up with! (assuming either of them work at all ha)